# AngularJS not putting an array in scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I'm attempting to use Angular JS and the angularSoundManager module to create a music player. I can get songs and the player to work fine, but when I tried changing the main array to be albums with an array of songs within each album, I keep getting a error that the albums variable is undefined.

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularSoundManager']).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.albums = [
        {
            id: 'one',
            title: 'album one',
            songs : [
                {
                    id: 'one',
                    title: 'Rain',
                    artist: 'YaNiggaPaul',
                    url: 'http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3'
                },
                {
                    id: 'four',
                    title: 'Angry cow sound?',
                    url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/data/audio/binaural/Mak.mp3'
                },
                {
                    id: 'five',
                    title: 'Things that open, close and roll',
                    url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/data/audio/binaural/Things%20that%20open,%20close%20and%20roll.mp3'
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            id: 'two',
            title: 'album two',
            songs : [
                {
                    id: 'two',
                    title: 'Walking',
                    url: 'http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/walking.mp3'
                },
                {
                    id: 'three',
                    title: 'Barrlping with Carl (featureblend.com)',
                    url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/misc/music/carl-3-barlp.mp3'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
}]);
```

Where the error is popping up in the module.

```
ngSoundManager.directive('playAll', ['angularPlayer', '$log',
function(angularPlayer, $log) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
            albums: '=playAll'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(event) {
                //first clear the playlist
                angularPlayer.clearPlaylist(function(data) {
                    $log.debug('cleared, ok now add to playlist');
                    //add songs to playlist
                    for(var i = 0; i < scope.albums[attrs.alid]['songs'].length; i++) {
                        angularPlayer.addTrack(scope.albums[attrs.alid]['songs'][i]);
                    }

                    if (attrs.play != 'false') {
                        //play first song
                        angularPlayer.play();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

more specifically

```
scope.albums[attrs.alid]['songs'].length
```

Errors with "cannot read property '0' of undefined.

All out of ideas, am I just structuring my table wrong?
Am new to Angular so any help is super appreciated. <3

EDIT :: call of directive (i think..?).

```
<li ng-repeat="album in albums">
                <button play-all="songs" my-playlist="playlist" data-alid="{{$index}}">{{album.title}}</button>
                <li ng-repeat="song in album.songs">
                    <button music-player="play" add-song="song">{{ song.title }}</button>
                </li>
            </li>
```

Comment: How are you calling your directive?

Comment: @PeterLaBanca edited. I believe that's what was wanted, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you are passing in a list of songs to the directive, not a list of albums. I'm thinking that you want to modify your directive to accept a single album, and iterate over its songs. In that case you will want to change your directive call to:

```
<button play-all="album" my-playlist="playlist">{{album.title}}</button>
```

Then you'll want to modify the directive definition to work off of a single album, instead of a list of albums. You also won't need to pass the album id anymore, as you are already passing the instance you care about:

```
ngSoundManager.directive('playAll', ['angularPlayer', '$log',
function(angularPlayer, $log) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
            album: '=playAll'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(event) {
                //first clear the playlist
                angularPlayer.clearPlaylist(function(data) {
                    $log.debug('cleared, ok now add to playlist');
                    //add songs to playlist
                    for(var i = 0; i < scope.album['songs'].length; i++) {
                        angularPlayer.addTrack(scope.album['songs'][i]);
                    }

                    if (attrs.play != 'false') {
                        //play first song
                        angularPlayer.play();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

As a side note - using the `link` function is not the best way to create an angular directive. 99% of your directives should only use the controller function and pass in the equivalent injectables that you need (which are $scope, $element, $attrs). That way, all of your directives follow similar conventions, and so you are more prepared when you dive into the world of Angular 2+

Comment: I love you and I definitely need to get more aquainted with Angular. Thanks for the tips! <3